# WebGL Three.js ColladaLoader Example Fails

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js, collada

I copied the exact (working) colladaLoader code from three.js on github, and put it on disk and sorted the dependancies. but instead of the monster.dae, 
I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'convertUpAxis' of undefined"
However the example works from the three.js github site.

No clues on the web at all.
What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to give us some more info.

On the [Collada example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html) The only code that references `convertUpAxis` is [Line 33](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html#L33).

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
```

As such, this suggests to me that the `THREE.ColladaLoader` instance either failed to create the instance or that the prototype isn't available in the first place. Either of these make it sound like you're missing a dependency.

Just a random guess on my part (I've never been a THREE.js expert) but are you perhaps using the Three.js file from the src folder instead of the build folder? The src version is just a stub with a requestAnimationFrame shim in it. The one from the [build folder](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/build), however, includes all of the submodules like the COLLADA loader that you need. Double check!

Comment: yeah its from the build folder 100%. this should be straightforward as its a simple copy and paste of an example. the plan was to just point it to my own .dae file and rawk! thanks for the help!

Comment: Well... development proceeds. its still not having it and its definately not as simple as it should be, but three boilerplate code has helped understand it a bit.